# Plotting Multiindex series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a time series of counts obtained with

```
data_g = data.groupby(['A', 'B'])
incidence = data_g.size()
incidence
```

And I get something like this:

```
A    B
A30.9  200801        4
       200802        9
       200803        9
       200804        5
       200805        3
...
```

*A* is a categorical variable with two values. *B* is *yearweek*. So this is weekly counts of two time-series (named after the values of A) over many years.

What I want, is to simply plot these series. I did not find a simple way to do this. What do you suggest?

Comment: what's wrong with `incidence.plot()` ? if you want bars - `incidence.plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: @MaxU, the problem with incidence.plot() is that the x axis labels are tuples like this('A30.9', 200801). So I don't get two separate series.